# how to use std::make_shared with a singleton instance

Tags: c++11, singleton, shared-ptr

I am trying to create a shared pointer of a singleton instance. Below is the way I am trying to do it.

### Singleton implementation:

```
    class MessageQueue
    {
        private:

            std::mutex _mutex;
            std::queue<std::string> _messageQueue;
            MessageQueue() {}

        public:

            MessageQueue(const MessageQueue& obj) = delete;
            MessageQueue& operator=(const MessageQueue& obj) = delete;
            static MessageQueue& getInstance()
            {
                static MessageQueue instance;
                return instance;
            }
            void pushMessage(std::string& message);
            std::string popMessage();
            void flushOut();
    };
```

### Using singleton instance to create a shared pointer:

```
    class Producer
    {
        private:

            std::shared_ptr<messagequeue::MessageQueue> _queue;

        public:

            Producer()
            {
                if(!_queue)
                {
                    auto& instance = messageq::MessageQueue::getInstance();
                    _queue = std::make_shared<messageq::MessageQueue>(instance);
                }
            }
            Producer(const Producer& obj);
            Producer& operator=(const Producer& obj);
    };
```

Now, the problem is with this much, the code doesn't compile because the copy constructor of the singleton class is deleted. If, I define the copy constructor, it does get compiled, but then it's not much of a singleton class anymore now then.

So, what is the best way to achieve this? My objective is that I want to make a shared_ptr instance variable of a class instance and the shared resource would be a singleton object.

Please help here.

Comment: Why do you need a shared pointer to a singleton?

Comment: Because I need the same message queue to be shared between the producer and consumer.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is about shared ownership, not shared access. Its a singleton, its shared by design, but nobody owns it.

Comment: Okay, got it. But, provided I still want to do it, is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ensure that you create the queue first and only after the producers and consumers, so that they get destroyed first, you don't need a smart pointer to the queue. Producer and consumers can just keep a plain pointer to the queue in this case.

Shared ownership saves you from thinking about who owns what and their lifetimes, however, that leads to poor designs in 99% of cases.